# Inner classe constructor in java

Tags: java, inner-classes

Hi I have a program like this.

1. interface

   ```
   package Sarvari.pack1;
   public interface Inter
   {
       void f();
   }
   ```
2. An outer class and Inner class:

   ```
   package Sarvari.pack2;
   import Sarvari.pack1.*;
   public class Outer
   {
       protected class Inner implements Inter
       {
           Inner() {//only public is working not protected or default;
               System.out.println("constructor of inner class");
           }

           public void f(){
               System.out.println("f method in inner class");
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. a class that extends the outer class:

   ```
   package sarvari;

   import sarvari.pack2.*;
   import sarvari.pack1.*;
   public class Coffee extends sarvari.pack2.Outer{
       public Inter met(){
            return new Inner();
       }
       public static void main(String[] args){
           new Coffee().met().f();
       }
   }
   ```

My questions are

1. is why I have to declare the constructor of the Inner class as public? why I cant access it as default?
2. If the protected access of Inner class is coming to the constructor, then even if I kept the access as protector to the constructor, its not working..only public is working..can anyone explain this behavior?

Comment: You say thant the class in your 3rd piece of code extends the outer class but it actually extends the inner class. Is that a lapsus ?

Comment: Your code doesn't compile whatever visibility modifier you put on the constructor. Didn't you want to extend Outer instead of Outer.Inner ? In that case it compiles with any modifier (except private of course).

Comment: `Coffee` is not extending `Outer`. `Outer` just happens to be part of the fully qualified class name for `Inner`. The way the code is written `new Coffee().f()` will have the same result as `new Coffee().met().f()`.

Comment: I know, and that's why it isn't compiling. Outer.Inner makes no sense because Inner is not a static inner class. It requires a instance of Outer to be defined. This is what I understand from the compile error I get when compiling his code.

Comment: its just copy mistake :( I actually extended Outer. but still I am getting the error that the inner class constructor to be public

Comment: Waog gave you the correct answer (correct since you edited it).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is, that `Coffee` is in another package than `Inner`. From another package `Coffee` can only access `public` members of `Inner`, since it's not a Child-Class of `Inner`.

Another problem is the package named *java*. It's prohibited to use it. Use another name for your custom classes.

You can use this `Coffee` class as a workaround, If you need to access the `Inner`-Constructor from `Coffee`, but don't want to make it public:

```
package java2;

import java2.pack2.*;
import java2.pack1.*;

public class Coffee extends Outer {

    private class Inner2 extends Inner {
    }

    public Inter met() {
        return new Inner2();
    }

    public static void main(String[] sarvari) {
        new Coffee().met().f();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes but I am extending the Outer class right.. so I can access its protected stuff...

Comment: yes, but you can't access the protected stuffs protected stuff.